# What is the output of this arduino code?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

My Arduino code is:

```
String myString;
void setup() {
  // initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
    }

 myString.reserve(26);
 myString = "i=";
 myString += "1234";
 myString += ", is that ok?";

 // print the String:
  Serial.println(myString);
 }

void loop() {
 // nothing to do here
}
```

Comment: *"i=1234, is that ok?"*, apparently.

Comment: thanks bro .Patrick Trentin

Answer (score 0):

**O/P**: "i=1234, is that ok?"

Why so silly Question?

Is there any Special Reason or any math trick?